# Does anyone have good strategies for creating a workshop for feature sets?

Tags: features, workshop

- **Goal**: identify features that are the most important to our end users so we can determine which features will go into the MVP and which features we might put into future iterations
- I have run a Top Task Analysis in the past as a quantitative survey to get this info, however, that would be a poor fit for this set of end users because the product is small and for an internal audience

I guess my question is, has anyone run a successful workshop that identifies a feature set for their product? Do you have any resources or strategies I can use to meet my stated goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “Sprint” by Jake Knapp has a framework you might find useful.

Comment: Running a workshop to determine what users need doesn't sound right. Gathering real user problems and needs through user research is probably better. This allows you to run a workshop on opportunities afterwards based on real user insights.

Comment: strategyzer.com/test might be a helpful resource as well

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find some good resources on Atlassian's [Team Playbook](https://www.atlassian.com/team-playbook) where there are a number of plays relating to product features and prioritization.

There are also other known models that have been used to prioritze or classify product features, such as the [Kano Model of Customer Satisfaction](https://www.career.pm/briefings/kano-model) that takes you through a process of understanding what are the features that are fundamental to the users and the ones that will delight them (note that you have to get the basic features right first anyway).